# Questions removed months later

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I just noticed that two questions I asked at the beginning of last year were then removed 6-7 months later.  Is there any chance I can get a heads-up as to why?

[This one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56847/outsourcing-a-private-project-can-it-be-done) may have been too subjective, but I certainly can't see why [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42685/sql-plan-guide-comparison-syncing) was nuked...

Answer (score 3):

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56847/outsourcing-a-private-project-can-it-be-done

This one probably could have been improved and focused with a good edit to reword the question from:

- Can it be done?  I don't know, can it be done to study the effects of Bengal Tiger mating practices in zero-G environments?  Certainly it could be with enough time, effort and money so *Can it be done?* is the wrong question to ask.
- What is the best way to outsource development and manage potential quality issues?  This is a much better question and is probably what you really wanted to know anyway.

Regardless, it wasn't closed for quality, it was closed because this question has been asked before and there were a number of excellent answers that you could have benefited from.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42685/sql-plan-guide-comparison-syncing

> Can anyone suggest a good way to sync plan guides for a database across multiple environments? (dev/prod etc). It seems that vs2010 database project schema comparison does not cater for this...

I can't speak for Mark, but I feel that he probably closed this because it is a very specific question about a very specific situation with a very specific software.  He felt it was too specific to be of any real benefit to future visitors.  For more information see the FAQ.

As far as deletion, this may have been in an effort to clean up the culmination of closed questions that have no hope of improvement.

Comment: If not programmers.SE, do you feel there is another stack-exchange site that I could ask questions similar to the second one?  Or does the close (instead of migration) mean the question is not relevant anywhere on the network?

Comment: @StaffordWilliams The only other place I could think of would be StackOverflow but I doubt that it would have been a good question there either. To be perfectly honest I would not close a question as too localized unless I really had a deep understanding of the subject matter, which in this case I don't.  I can't speak for Mark on this as he may have understood or at least had a good understanding of what it was you were asking.  Hopefully he will chime in on this and offer his perspective.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts.  I don't know who Mark is, but if he has the deep understanding you speak of, perhaps he can answer the question for me :)

Comment: I can't see the second question now that I'm not a moderator anymore and trying to remember why a single question got closed a year after the fact is pointless, but it was almost certainly deleted as part of routine cleanup efforts. Note @maple_shaft you should be able to see if the closure was in response to any flags from the mod menu.

Comment: But the fact that it was closed for 6-7 months before deletion and I haven't been a moderator for 4 months (meaning it's been at least that long since it's been deleted) is a strong indication the question was completely abandoned and had no chance of being improved to address whatever reason the question was closed. If it's so important, it's better off re-asked—bearing in mind SE's quality guidelines—at this point.

Comment: "What is the best way..." smells like _shopping_. [Atwood's transform](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124930/165773 "what's this?") would likely make it into something like **"what do I need to learn / take into account to tell the best way..."**

Comment: @gnat totally agree with this, but the opportunity to re-word the question does not exist for me when it's been closed

Comment: @maple_shaft any chance you can give me access to the sql-plan guide question so i can review it, and perhaps ask it elsewhere?

Comment: @StaffordWilliams I suppose the answer really doesn't help those of us who are not moderators or those who do not have 10k rep.  I added the body of the question into my answer.

Comment: @StaffordWilliams closed questions can (and actually are expected to) be edited and improved by author. It's only deleted and locked questions which can not be edited without prior help from moderator